# Wearables for tracking heart rate

Tags: android, wearable-technology

Recently I started a study on long term context of a user. For that I concentrate on Android Wear specifically; I am looking into heart rate sensors. My goal is to map the users heart rate over a extended period. After collection I would then focus on error correction and data reduction, resulting in an analysis specific to the user.

In order to make this possible I would need 'continuous readings from a smart wearable'; meaning that i need at least a heart rate reading every 5-10 minutes. Since I am new to the smart watch/wearables I thought I'd ask a few questions here.

1. I am looking into all sorts of wearables. For example Fitbit, Polar etc for more enthusiastic users. But the internet is huge, and I am looking for some opinions on what platform to choose. Currently I am looking into Fitbit, Polar (with a personal app for this project), and an android wear device (currently moto 360). Please recommend one of these models. I would particularly like details of any programming interface (how easy is it to retrieve data) and strong positives and negatives of the device.
2. I am looking into the Huawei watch, but this model does not offer an always on heart rate sensor. Would it be possible to produce an app that measures a pulse every 5 minutes and sends that data to an app on a phone?

Keep in mind I need to access the heart rate data. So if there isn't a platform available to receive the data besides a native app, it won't be of use.

Comment: Hi Enias. I've edited your question a bit; since this site is primarily aimed at hardware recommendations, I've made that part the primary question. I've also removed your original second question, because answers to it will be very opinion-based, which doesn't lend itself to keeping a site objective. Good question, though. I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: *pokes question with a stick*

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is very opinion based... at the end of the day, it is your decision. I have a Motorola Moto Watch 2nd Gen, the starting price is £239ish. I like watches with a circular display, so I chose this watch. At that time, the Huawei watch was a bit more costly. Despite the 'flat tire' display of the Moto Watch (the black bit at the bottom of the display) I sort of liked the watch. It's got great specs.

My best tip for you is to look at reviews and most importantly the specifications of the device itself. Trust me, the specs will tell you a lot about the watch!

Hope I helped!

Sid